# Get google sheet filter view data with api call

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

There's really very little code I can show here. I'm calling a google sheets spreadsheet using the api with node.js.

Within the spreadsheet, I have created a bunch of `filter views`. Is there a way to tell the api to call the filtered data instead of just getting all the data in the sheet.

```
const dataFromGoogleSheets = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${
  config.spreadsheetId
}/values:batchGet?ranges=${"Sheet1"}&majorDimension=ROWS&key=${
  config.apiKey
}`;
```

**UPDATE**

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
    {
      spreadsheetId: "mySpreadSheetID",
      filterViewId: 121321321,
      title: "Filters"
    }
)
```

Comment: Is this question about [tag:google-apps-script] or about [tag:google-sheets-api]? Have you already reviewed the corresponding docs in https://developers.google.com?

Comment: I think it's a google-sheets-api question. I've looked at the docs. They suggest adding in `/edit#gid=66666&fvid=121321321`. When I add that into the  `const dataFromGoogleSheets = https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${
  config.spreadsheetId
}/edit#gid=66666&fvid=121321321/values:batchGet?ranges=${"Sheet1"}&majorDimension=ROWS&key=${
  config.apiKey
}`; ` it returns `invalid json response body at the address`. @Rubén

Comment: @bp123 You want to retrieve the filtered values from the sheet which has the basic filter using Node.js. If my understanding correct, do you use googleapis of Node.js or others?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do using node. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#filter_views @Tanaike

Comment: @bp123 Thank you for replying. I edited your tag.

Comment: @bp123 In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated what I'm trying to do. I've moved over to the API. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#filterview . I get his error Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "filterViewId"

Comment: @bp123 Thank you for replying. In the current stage, unfortunately, the filtered values cannot be directly retrieved using `filterViewId`. So for example, as a workaround, how about retrieving the filtered values by using `criteria` of the filter view?

Comment: @Tanaike how do you use criteria to do that?

Comment: @bp123 Thank you for replying. In my proposal, at first, it creates the basic filter using the criteria. Then, the values filtered with the basic filter are retrieved. Because the values filtered by the basic filter can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch data from Sheets API or Google Apps Script with an active FilterView.

As [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned in the comments, you can fetch the criteria from the FilterView and reprocess it on top of the data.

You can also file a Feature Request for this on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).